# ¿Existe algún método en C++ que permita obtener el nombre de los métodos de una clase a partir de una instancia de la misma?

Tags: c++

¿Existe algún método en C++ que permita obtener el nombre de los métodos de una clase a partir de una instancia de la misma? Es decir, si tengo una variable de tipo "MyClass", ¿puedo obtener el nombre de los métodos definidos en "MyClass" a partir de esa variable?

De antemano gracias por su tiempo.
Lo que sigue es la causa de mi pregunta, pero no es necesario leerlo para responderla. Lo que estoy es tratando de hacer una adaptación de lo que hace Kent Beck en su libro Test-Driven Development By Example en la segunda parte del mismo.
El ejercicio el autor lo hace en el lenguaje de programación piton. Yo estoy tratando de hacerlo en c++. Si no te has leído el leído el libro lo que quiero hacer es algo como lo siguiente:

```
WasRun test = WasRun("testMethod");
cout << endl << test.wasRun; /* imprime el numero cero “0” */
test.run(); /* de alguna forma mágica ejecute el método  "testMethod" que cambia la propiedad wasRun de cero “0” a uno “1” */
cout << endl << test.wasRun; /* imprime el número uno “1” */
```

Quiero que el código sea 100% dinámico, no me sirve una estructura de control switch en el constructor para ir preguntando por los diferentes métodos de la clase.

Otra cosa que creo que me puede ayudar es lo siguiente. Supongamos que tengo dos funciones, una llamada “saludar” y otra llamada “despedirme”. Quiero hacer que de alguna forma un código parecido al siguiente que funcione en c++.

```
String nombreDeLaFucion;
nombreDeLaFucion = " saludar";
nombreDeLaFucion(); // que ejecute la función saludar
nombreDeLaFucion = " despedirme";
nombreDeLaFucion(); // que ejecute la función despedirme
```

Si eres un héroe y has llegado hasta aquí, la utilidad que tengo pensado dale a la respuesta que me den para resolver mi problema es algo como lo que sigue, pero con un ciclo. Este código funciono para mí. Si alguien tiene una mejor idea que se sienta libre de decirme.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>

void uno() {
    std::cout << "uno siii" << std::endl;
}

void dos() {
    std::cout << "dos nooo" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>> funciones;
    funciones["uno"] = uno;
    funciones["dos"] = dos;
    
    std::string nombreFuncion;
    std::function<void()> funcion;
    
    nombreFuncion = "uno";
    funcion = funciones[nombreFuncion];
    funcion(); // ejecuta la función uno()
    
    nombreFuncion = "dos";
    funcion = funciones[nombreFuncion];
    funcion(); // ejecuta la función dos()
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Jo, que fácil responder a eso que preguntas: **NO**. Sin embargo, mediante herramientas externas, es posible algo parecido. Puedes consultar, por ejemplo, los [Meta Objetos de Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/metaobjects.html).

Comment: @Trauma la respuesta es **SI**, pero a partir de C++26 con las herramientas de reflexión estática.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster jejeje ... igual habría que esperar un poco para esa afirmación tan categórica ¿ no te parece ?

Comment: @Trauma la reflexión está [oficialmente aceptada dentro del estándar C++26 y en camino para ser completada en dicho estándar](https://herbsutter.com/2023/11/11/trip-report-autumn-iso-c-standards-meeting-kona-hi-usa/).

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Existe algún método en C++ que permita obtener el nombre de los métodos de una clase a partir de una instancia de la misma? Es decir, si tengo una variable de tipo "MyClass", ¿puedo obtener el nombre de los métodos definidos en "MyClass" a partir de esa variable?

La buena noticia es que si, la mala noticia es que será a partir de C++26 mediante la nueva funcionalidad de reflexión. CLang tiene una implementación cuyo uso puedes ver en [este código de ejemplo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAHADMpAAOqAqETgwe3r56KWmOAkEh4SxRMQm2mPYFDEIETMQEWT5%2BXJXVGXUNBEVhkdF6CvWNzTltQ929JWUSAJS2qF7EyOwc5vHByN5YANQm8W5OQ8SYrPvYJhoAguub25h7B5iqSdF4bIJiAPQnVNXnlxu1wImBYSQMIMebgIAE9Xsw2Ds2PVSDsmF4iDsAHQ4nbBfArBQA64AN1QeHQSK8mGOTAgaAYQx2Q3QIBA%2BOeAH0lABHakMFb7Q4MAk07E4857MwANlmgJMAHYrNcdqqdl40kYdgiaUkmCtmQRWSBnq9iO9GPVaGzfv94sqgVc1TsoCy2WgMVChTtgJgCJydZySULff6qqDLZyCEL8XhCajkUwAfFsF6DjswGsAKxuBiZ%2BbirFy%2B3yhUAEXlwNB4KYkKFsPhrAeABViVd0ZjUGamOgSDSIHLroqHc6NcFgNqmwo9Qa3SaXm8PlabZg/pgHPsHYDR5qJ13orWSApHmWfX7OfviIfiAoo0LbabiBBm8WLiWVWqGUNH2iMahmXgABeDz7KeobckBmBCpe15EimA6btun4CN%2BLzEL%2BmIcqoYqgYaxosEwADWmCclh3KYHyjCCgcaTAQCSqKhW76Os6LDUrS0HdkQN7nBAWE0sWW7lpWVwgmCEIgQcDaME2OytimgJkhSOxUF4AoZP2g43AxH6qmOWo6tO%2BoPHOpqLpaYgrmuG7MUhem7kioJlJyqkCjUx64eBbClNELlqQ4GS3tGBwPmhz6vohuk7F%2BIJoRh/60ZJYHnolQrec5rkBShvGCXZ0UobFSToR2/78R58SnnOBHEaRIpcry/LUW4qUKQxwm2VFbE0gQV5pU5vmZe5vFlblQ7CUOVbibWknQnCMmIvJFzXCV%2BWMj1XgOH2CgIWNI5qvpE6GTOJlGmyZnmkulkgA%2BNlblFB2rccG3ceVyX%2BjFxDPUed4hau9BhS%2ByZ7aqMU/itiUnme/otW4H1fTx8GjU6yFrWDf54nV2GvXhbLVSRZENVRUE0ZB9FWO1d3I6qXUcQccObQj2B8ZjAmRdpFYTVcT0OHJ3WlsDvNDAOkNYFQ6K0MFAvNt1zMEHKbUc1TOwAH7S0L8vk4reVqwQUrSjB3HWNYCHMc6Ot6wbJBG5YstI3lSmUplGRcMLw6MXlwS607AhmK7So7CcBBLAwbsU3s41Kw7Kn%2BRk8S2%2BHmse4I0fqQIkjx8OAd%2BsHodMRY4eK0VeAktNIBJ7rLBRnzCts%2B7HWidWElQtJOpyW2Uckr5qARNofqoPSBVyXrWlu1Fc4errQreuYZgeGtn0MzSZc5iHZhmGzzr09xNJCotJuU864%2BLJPBzT2vABiMcCEvJgrzPG9qt7IRwW4e922Pp0oMfaZuFKZgAPLdl7CcBQy9cz31NmqGCwCd4HDfrXCOgJPZIiYMEHa2kBad2IBeHufdnzV01kjZ0gdg47A0AgxWHB5jWg4FmXgfgOBaFIKgTgbhrb5wUIsZYIEzDxB4KQAgmgqHzEIiALMGh9CcEkPQoRzDOC8FARIwRjCqGkDgLAGAiAv5gjoNEcglA0A6PoDELYhhgCchujUPgdAQQ3koBEWRERggNBhJwfhTjmDEBhP/XBDg3G8EMUuf%2BDBaCuJUaQLAEQvDADcGIWgoDuC8CwARIw4hwn4BOAFTuCSmHPHXBiVY/DPZVFkbQPAEQrxeI8FgWRPV3j%2BPmH8JgwAFAADU8CYAAO6AMYP4mQggRBiHYFIfp8glBqFkboNoBgjAoHYfocpoDIDzC7O5eRzCsHmiwEsgc7R1w1BcCKUYrRSCBGCH0HyMQ2h5HSAIY5uRUi3IYFMfoVy9lZVqMMJongWiDHDB8rojQXmXMGF8%2B54wvnApmFweYnClgrDmJI2hMjwksI4DsVQsRpQAFppSSGijMicEBLEZFmC6XAhASBSj4bMXgyitCzHmAgU4WAYi7NEeIpF0jSAsBAPEeIWJ%2BVCuFSK6UpAGFMLRQokASihHzHUVo4%2BSQMT6IHkY6IoQmycExTivFBKzEuhJQIWlpz8DcQpHofgAzRDiBGVasZKh1DhKmaQTpV4kgNKRXQ8Vsi0X/wxMq3WqAqAYqxbi/FpitTEr%2Bvs0lLoPDqvQusGFdK5VMpZQMXZNDuW8rMBoLEMozAAE4sySHiNKIt0pYjFp9ai9ZiiBFyrUZoiASA8nID/GQCgEAGgtOUIYKoQgECoE6Qw/hhikh0FrBkftIRaBDpHRKgJqBE0oEJRYmNHzSATt0cQTVbB1k7uMf64Qw7R2yPbVcYgLT1ntrqPgBhvB7WDNtdIe1ihHWTL0ISuZlhrALIiDslZSQ1kcF4KgTZFIl7LNIJ9QQFpmyoE8EBhY8Lhm2CNMEWdg6z1jrpScdgEi3VMA9Yk6hnBvVLrkRwbA2EO3cVDbqiNhLDWbpqGSiAbC/2WFRBShjyaTX0uEVy3gvLJDSixJIDQ8QFRcDXpWotCQFRZizLWyV9aZWNpUYy0gHKJE0PiCi9TYGtMMvIxwMwRnwPrKEzprBaRnCSCAA%3D%3D%3D):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/reflect>

template <typename meta, auto ... indices>
void muestra(const std::index_sequence<indices ...> &)
{
    using namespace std::experimental::reflect;

    ((std::cout << get_name_v<get_element_t<indices, meta>> << '\n'), ...);
}

template <typename T>
auto operadores()
{
    using namespace std::experimental::reflect;

    using operators = get_operators_t<reflexpr(T)>;
    constexpr auto size = get_size<operators>();
    constexpr auto indexes = std::make_index_sequence<size>{};

    muestra<operators>(indexes);
}

template <typename T>
void funciones()
{
    using namespace std::experimental::reflect;

    using member_functions = get_member_functions_t<reflexpr(T)>;
    constexpr auto size = get_size<member_functions>();
    constexpr auto indexes = std::make_index_sequence<size>{};

    muestra<member_functions>(indexes);
}

template <typename T>
auto constructores()
{
    using namespace std::experimental::reflect;

    using constructors = get_constructors_t<reflexpr(T)>;
    constexpr auto size = get_size<constructors>();
    constexpr auto indexes = std::make_index_sequence<size>{};

    muestra<constructors>(indexes);
}

struct Test
{
    Test() = default;
    Test(int){}
    ~Test(){}

    Test &operator++();
    Test &operator++(int);

    void funcion1() {}
    int funcion2() { return{}; }
    void funcion3(int) {}
    int funcion4(int) { return{}; }
private:
    int m_test{};
};

template <typename T>
void ver_objeto(const T &)
{
    std::cout << "Constructores:\n";
    constructores<T>();

    std::cout << "Funciones:\n";
    funciones<T>();

    std::cout << "Operadores:\n";
    operadores<T>();
}

int main()
{
    ver_objeto(Test{});
    return 0;
}
```

Que tiene la siguiente salida:

```
Constructores:
Test
Test
Test
Funciones:
funcion1
funcion2
funcion3
funcion4
Operadores:
operator++
operator++
```

---

> Quiero hacer que de alguna forma un código parecido al siguiente que funcione en c++.
>
> ```cpp
> String nombreDeLaFucion;
> nombreDeLaFucion = " saludar";
> nombreDeLaFucion(); // que ejecute la función saludar
> nombreDeLaFucion = " despedirme";
> nombreDeLaFucion(); // que ejecute la función despedirme
> ```

Si esto tiene relación con la parte anterior, debes saber que (a no ser que asumas que la instancia de la clase a usar) no se puede. Para llamar a una función miembro (lo que nombras método) de un objeto C++ necesitas dos cosas:

1. Un puntero a función miembro.
2. Una instancia del objeto sobre el que usar la función.

Utilizando las herramientas de recursión próximamente disponibles en C++26, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

1. Crear unas funciones que nos devuelvan un mapa nombre-función a partir de un tipo de dato:

   ```cpp
   template <typename meta, auto ... indices>
   auto function_map(const std::index_sequence<indices ...> &) -> 
   std::map<std::string, decltype(get_pointer_v<get_element_t<0, meta>>)>
   {
       return
       {
           {
               get_name_v<get_element_t<indices, meta>>,
               get_pointer_v<get_element_t<indices, meta>>
           } ...
       };

   }

   template <typename T>
   auto funciones()
   {
       using member_functions = get_member_functions_t<reflexpr(T)>;
       constexpr auto size = get_size<member_functions>();

       return function_map<member_functions>(std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
   }
   ```
2. Para evitar crear instancias de mapas de funciones en cada llamada, añadiremos una función plantilla:

   ```cpp
   template <typename T>
   auto funciones_de = funciones<T>();
   ```
3. Con una función que reciba un nombre de función y una instancia de objeto, podemos llamar a la función del objeto (si está disponible):

   ```cpp
   template <typename T>
   void llamar_a_funcion(const std::string &fn, T &t)
   {
       auto &funciones = funciones_de<T>;

       if (auto found = funciones.find(fn); found != funciones.end())
           (t.*found->second)();
       else
           std::cout << "La funcion " << fn << " no existe en el objeto " << &t << ".\n";
   }
   ```

Con esta colección de funciones este programa:

```cpp
#define FN std::cout << this << ": " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

struct S
{
    void f1() { FN; }
    void f2() { FN; }
};

class C
{
public:    
    void f3() { FN; }
    void f4() { FN; }
};

union U
{
    void f5() { FN; }
    void f6() { FN; }
};

int main()
{
    S a, b;
    C c, d;
    U e, f;

    for (const auto &fn : {"f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7", "f8"})
    {
        std::cout
            << "\n\nLlamando la funcion '" << fn << "' sobre instancias de:\n"
            << "struct S\n";
        llamar_a_funcion(fn, a);
        llamar_a_funcion(fn, b);
        std::cout
            << "class C\n";
        llamar_a_funcion(fn, c);
        llamar_a_funcion(fn, d);
        std::cout
            << "union U\n";
        llamar_a_funcion(fn, e);
        llamar_a_funcion(fn, f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Produce la siguiente salida:

```
Llamando la funcion 'f1' sobre instancias de:
struct S
0x7ffd40d0e6b8: void S::f1()
0x7ffd40d0e6b0: void S::f1()
class C
La funcion f1 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6a8.
La funcion f1 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6a0.
union U
La funcion f1 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e698.
La funcion f1 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e690.


Llamando la funcion 'f2' sobre instancias de:
struct S
0x7ffd40d0e6b8: void S::f2()
0x7ffd40d0e6b0: void S::f2()
class C
La funcion f2 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6a8.
La funcion f2 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6a0.
union U
La funcion f2 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e698.
La funcion f2 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e690.


Llamando la funcion 'f3' sobre instancias de:
struct S
La funcion f3 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6b8.
La funcion f3 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6b0.
class C
0x7ffd40d0e6a8: void C::f3()
0x7ffd40d0e6a0: void C::f3()
union U
La funcion f3 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e698.
La funcion f3 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e690.


Llamando la funcion 'f4' sobre instancias de:
struct S
La funcion f4 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6b8.
La funcion f4 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6b0.
class C
0x7ffd40d0e6a8: void C::f4()
0x7ffd40d0e6a0: void C::f4()
union U
La funcion f4 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e698.
La funcion f4 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e690.


Llamando la funcion 'f5' sobre instancias de:
struct S
La funcion f5 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6b8.
La funcion f5 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6b0.
class C
La funcion f5 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6a8.
La funcion f5 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6a0.
union U
0x7ffd40d0e698: void U::f5()
0x7ffd40d0e690: void U::f5()


Llamando la funcion 'f6' sobre instancias de:
struct S
La funcion f6 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6b8.
La funcion f6 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6b0.
class C
La funcion f6 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6a8.
La funcion f6 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6a0.
union U
0x7ffd40d0e698: void U::f6()
0x7ffd40d0e690: void U::f6()


Llamando la funcion 'f7' sobre instancias de:
struct S
La funcion f7 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6b8.
La funcion f7 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6b0.
class C
La funcion f7 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6a8.
La funcion f7 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6a0.
union U
La funcion f7 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e698.
La funcion f7 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e690.


Llamando la funcion 'f8' sobre instancias de:
struct S
La funcion f8 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6b8.
La funcion f8 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6b0.
class C
La funcion f8 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6a8.
La funcion f8 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e6a0.
union U
La funcion f8 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e698.
La funcion f8 no existe en el objeto 0x7ffd40d0e690.
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIAAcAJykAA6oCoRODB7evnppGY4CIWGRLDFxktJ2mA5ZQgRMxAQ5Pn4BNXUCDU0EJRHRsQnJCo3NrXlctmN9oQPlQ1UAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQmO25Oo8SYrKfYJhoAgrv7h5gnZyxMKbf3T2Z7DAOXmOpzcl1CwB%2Bj2egNe7zcmFUKVieDYgjEAHorlR7AQoU9Hl4MkYjsw2AoUkxNkdRugQCBEcjiKjGI1aPTsbjTlZoY8CJgWCkDPz4QQAJ7IslvNiNUhHJheIhHAB0qqOoXwmwU%2BIVSqoXkBRQYAH1PikIGgGKMaQQ6SANYjjUoAI5eRibUEavBalWq24nMwANiWRwAtP7afSzaDIyBwUY5VgDuLkdBMARjWlQvziMaAG6g4Dp42YehojN4s4aOUypg/HbYJb4kwAdh5DyOnaOVwI6wYvy7JzbA8HXdb7dHk6ORYzUvzheLpYFrONlfODE1mAUNfTdYbt1II6nXZnmdQ2di87Op6X5dXno33q3O8a9buj2PrYAIr7lUeh1%2B3K/MBLaAbyDz8oKwpvKCKaMKwbwACo6oqqBHPqgJZFuEBNtCw4fl2RIQkcbALLmGFdFa7w/qepEVMaFFGgo95nJyjLEBAiFNvuOwTl2lqjOx8qoTSeAAF4wTsNHFhkEmgnRl6MVk2oNjhQHgYOPZ9uhBqUaaXzyQK9FKQIKnYBAsafAA1pgxoOqoTqYK67qYDG4mufuw6gdx7bfsBfICkKTAirBErwWwRzIfujy6mhFFYcxIJSTpmECFuoJReZPn%2BRBgXQaKYVSpF%2BJ5ue6BHLQBifLmTAMbpWQWqZBA2na8bAAGgZUAwcqIR1BC4U8%2BEdl2sUdfFaUKNRKXIAlxpYBl9a%2BQRnZ4FQRwQKN/AGuVpw/uNYQKMqNAbtQDA%2BehawbkcYBgLt00Jcqrg4QNx4QAQyoAFRbRu4YNkolroEsam8f%2BpZKP%2Bg6xmgirwqCAZmEETD3QI8Ow2c6EMGjbiowwaGIngglHIwRO0EcqBRNo6ZoeYZhY31dM03%2BACsbj9mYZjqYNYEEn8OxYMdbwAGLhC19LQ81oJwwQCAEwz7MgKjkvo8axrKAAStgiGIQAmsagtyOEbiIQAkgA8uEKt02A2wsww1s5ZcXgOEcQggXxnalXg5VUFwOFDhYRzC9yAH/p73tmH746B%2BEwd%2BXhgEg%2BBBxMAok1uG7vwpF4US0N6CtjstRxh%2BhOyR220ex6BodlehkhlwHQe8SH8ec78BpZEccgZ4XxdUEz9cV03cfDR7NdUIGA%2BNwHw9%2BYnPPZiRTChGpeHuy78pylEnODtjyCJtvXZyETcpUK3hf8MQ60Cc1o3mJ1mMK%2BONM%2BzTcrPxz7Nv%2BzVA7K/8NUJIP%2Bz8mZAO/oGUBZgqAtggVQeINNvwvTHENY8UM1h4kLp%2BM4cN4G2xMLbIIVVDDoDQgYZGmN7bszpl1OWZhrY0nJlcdUVpGiYRTkcLAIA8Gs3gRgqcStsY00ds7V2uD2YH0nJVVgTRjS1X2qdOUTBsq8M7JI6qMi6qpQYPIo4UQlEj1HKgxUEM%2BFYPRjTZOqcjjp1ERzOex5VHSNkfVAQ2jkB6PsYQmqGiZouK6omdxU5DHoP0Zg9OZj2btxRl3Gx4jRwOK8XIvxRMAkSM8eoxJ3V0IpObjzTS6ZtIaFblXR4HAVjsg4EzXgfgOBaFIKgTg6dLDWHoesakuweCkAIJoUpKwrIgCZtWcpkgqndLqZwXgCgQDVi6TU0ppA4CwBgIgFAqBBR0FiOQSgaA1n0DiMnIwxo2KUT4HQHMkyIBRFGVEUITQxScA6dc5gxAxSmwprUGZHTtnllNgwWgdzZmkCwFELwwA3BiFoJM7gvAsCfCMOIAF%2BArh1DzFuUZiJaiKi2B0i85Tam5yiMQW5HgOEAoIMyFg9y5k4iYMABQAA1PAmAADuptJSUpkIIEQYh2BSA5fIJQahRm6CmAYIwKBrDWH0HgKIkzIArFQCkJi4y6kouIMyLAsqcK2CXJRFwG4Jh%2BCmMEOYZQKj5HSJkAQBrzWFCyP0U1QwpidCND0cYng2h6GdfUGY9rBhxCdTMa1Abei%2BrIhIFYCg1gbB5WUzglTSDVNqfUjgRxVDxEDKGQMkgjj7PahAI5RoQwQFwIQEgAYdhcCWLwGZWglgrAQNcLAcQtV9IGfoTgwzSAUp2DsZUPb%2B0DsHYGBNozk0TKmZ07pKwFnLLQVnAgmzGo7NiOEBCnA00ZqzTm0VeaC1ZCrYEfARB1V6H4Jy0Q4heVnv5SodQALhWkCZYSlIlLY0VJGQC5NptFTzrJmtDdmbs25vWnugQRaPDLsvu0g9NaemkAbUwJtlA32dopWYDQyogxmESEzSQOxAyJEDPEbDI7P3KsmdMqd8ylkQCQOi5AqEyAUA2sQWlyhDCliEAgVATLqmfNWSkOgwUsjsbCLQLjPHE28G2YJ3ZKAd2HMwDid5WRSAyfWcQVdbBlXqd2d%2B4Q3HeNotULUB4rHIW8How0fA1TeDXq5Ze6Q17FC3qFXoHd4qmmWClTK%2BA8rFXKWVagVV6rUVytIMQA0jg2CIVQJ4TVEao2bE9baUIonOOGb49Wq47BqxPq%2BK%2B9t77SNJs4NgEzDHj2pvTYB7dhhd1KdxPu9ajSrDeaOCWqr0Hq1TpQ7wClkhAzKkkBoHYLYuDs0I4keIY2mZMxK7wMdtgJ2wbraQVtgzOA7A/aVjgPXZlrfKWYHbi3lWrZWKqjIzhJBAA)</kbd>.

Ten en cuenta que el código asume que todas las funciones tendrán la misma firma y que asume que todas las funciones serán públicas.